# Vue js method returning undefined

Tags: vue.js, promise, state, vuex

I have a Vue Js app utilizing VueX. In one of my components I am calling a method to truncate some text. This truncate method lives in a separate file used for small helper functions. And the piece of text I am trying to truncate is being pulled from the state that gets pulled from a database.

Suppose this is the user object in my state:

```
userState: {
   name: "John Doe",
   bio: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum laborum amet, dolores molestiae voluptates ea animi fugit quo repudiandae facilis.",
   age: 35
}
```

In my template I am calling the bio as such:

```
<p>{{ truncate(userState.bio, 20, "...") }}</p>
```

In my component methods I have the following method:

```
const helpers = require("@/utilities/helpers");
methods: {
  truncate(text, length, ending) {
     return helpers.truncateText(text, length, ending);
  }
```

}

And the method in my helpers file is:

```
export const truncateText = (str, length, ending) => {
   if (length == null) {
      length = 100;
   }
   if (ending == null) {
      ending = '...';
   }
   if (str.length > length) {
      return str.substring(0, length - ending.length) + ending;
   } else {
      return str;
   }
}
```

And the message i get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

But the strange part is that the truncated text renders in the dom...even with the error in the console.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT:**

I should mention that calling `user,bio` without the truncate method i get no error at all and the bio renders ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that the initial state of `userState.bio` is *undefined*, and the error comes from the initial rendering when the data is not updated; Try add another string check in your condition to eliminate the error:

```
if (str && str.length > length) {
}
```